# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find happens only when the library has few versions (i think)

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

I'm trying to link opencv libraries in eclipse for a c++ project.
When I link libraries that have one instance in the folder it seems to recognize it, but doesn't recognize when the libraries have few instances (perhaps the term instance isn't so accurate, i'm not quite sure what is the meaning of these different versions of libraries).
Therefore the problem doesn't seem to be related to misuse of lib or wrong path, as i have seen in other questions.

This is what I get when building the project:

> ```
> 12:33:17 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test2 ****    
> make all     
> Building target: Test2    
> Invoking: GCC C++ Linker    
> g++ -L/usr/local/Matlab/2013b/bin/glnxa64 -o "Test2"  ./BilateralFilter.o ./main.o ./stdafx.o   -lopencv_core -lmwvision_res -lmwvision -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui    
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core    
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc    
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui    
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status    
> make: *** [Test2] Error 1
> ```

as you can see, the **mwvision** doesn't seem to have a problem, but the others do, and I think it has to do with them existing in multiple versions in the directory (but perhaps i'm wrong).
**opencv_core**, **opencv_imgproc** and **opencv_highgui** all have **.so.2.4** and **.so.2.4.2** versions.

These two links unfortunately did not provide an answer:
[ld linkage problems: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find [libraryname]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288444/ld-linkage-problems-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-libraryname)

[/usr/bin/ld: cannot find shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639723/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-shared-library)

Also I will mention that I have no use in Matlab, it's just where I found the libraries of opencv.

Comment: Do you have `lib<xxx>.a` files for all of these in the directory `/usr/local/Matlab/2013b/bin/glnxa64`? You probably need to add another `-L` option specifying where your opencv libs are actually placed.

Comment: no, only .so is what I see.
What do you mean by "where your opencv libs are actually placed"?

Comment: For linking, you need the stubs `libopencv_core.a`,`libopencv_imgproc.a`, etc.

Comment: **locate** command only found the **.so** libraries. Any idea of another way to search for it?

Comment: Where did you get the headers from ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/bilateralfilter/source/browse/trunk/BilateralFilter.cpp?r=3

Comment: You had some opencv headers included when compiling `./BilateralFilter.o ./main.o`, didn't you?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/bilateralfilter/source/browse/trunk/BilateralFilter.cpp?r=3

It's pretty much copy pasted from there. I changed the **TCHAR** use to **char***, but basically it's the same. And now i'm trying to run it.

Comment: "existing in multiple versions in the directory". Which directory?

Comment: Sigh! https://code.google.com/p/bilateralfilter/source/browse/trunk/InstallingOpenCV.txt?r=3

Comment: @n.m 
This directory: **/usr/local/Matlab/2013b/bin/glnxa64**

Comment: Are you sure the libraries have correct architecture for the platform (x86 vs x86_64)? Do you have symbolic links set up correctly (say libopencv_core.so pointing to libopencv_core.so.2 pointing to libopencv_core.so.2.4)?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ
Is there a problem with this website? Not reliable or something?

Comment: @n.m
**readlink libopencv_core.so.2.4** returned **libopencv_core.so.2.4.2**   
Whereas
**readlink libopencv_core.so.2.4.2** didn't return anything

Comment: @achie Did you read what's written in the link there? _`Additional Library Directories:  
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\lib"`_

Comment: I didn't find such directory in my download, so I tried to get over it in a different way. Was that a bad idea? What should I have done?

Comment: You need `libopencv_core.so` without any version that is a symbolic link to some specific version like `libopencv_core.so.2.4`. I presume you have verified that the libraries have the right architecture.

Comment: @n.m
I'm sorry, i'm not too strong with technical issues.
Regarding right architecture, does commiting "file <library>" any good? here's the output.
> 'cs302six2-3:/usr/local/Matlab/2013b/bin/glnxa64> file libopencv_core.so.2.4
 
> libopencv_core.so.2.4: symbolic link to `libopencv_core.so.2.4.2'   

> cs302six2-3:/usr/local/Matlab/2013b/bin/glnxa64> file libopencv_core.so.2.4.2

> libopencv_core.so.2.4.2: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped    <br/>
'

Is there a way to isolate the 2.4.2 version as it is not a symbolic link?

Comment: Sorry the comment came out not organized, i'm new here and couldn't find a way to break the lines. My intension is:
**file libopencv_core.so.2.4** gave output **libopencv_core.so.2.4: symbolic link to `libopencv_core.so.2.4.2'** whereas    **file libopencv_core.so.2.4.2** gave output **libopencv_core.so.2.4.2: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped**.

Comment: @achie _"Was that a bad idea?"_ Probably, yes. _"What should I have done?"_ Exactly what's written in the link, install the OpenCv library.

Comment: You are probably better off installing OpenCV from the repository. If you for some reason don't want to, then no, 2.4.2 is not and should not be isolated and it is not supposed to be a symbolic link. Files *.so without versions are supposed to be symbolic links. Do you have .so symbolic links without versions? If not, you need to create them (not recommended --- just open your package manager and install OpenCV).

Answer (score 0):

> opencv_core, opencv_imgproc and opencv_highgui all have .so.2.4 and .so.2.4.2 versions.

If you read this description of [external library versioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter5-5.html), you'll understand that the `.so.2.4` is a *runtime* name of the library, and not its *link-time* name.

In order to link, you need `.so` (without the version suffix).

Having `.so.2.4` but not `.so` usually comes about when you have e.g. `libopencv-core` package installed, but not `libopencv-core-dev`. The solution is to install the latter.